# Do People Prefer to watch TV/Movies on Tablets larger than 8 inches?

Tags: research, tablet, size

Recently I was told by a friend that most of watching users prefer larger tablet (more than 8 inch with ratio 80 /20). Because it is a big difference  I`am wondering if there is any research or statistics that actually gives a statistical preference

Comment: As one who used to work in film and TV, and am still on the fringes, we cringe at the very thought of tablets themselves.

Comment: Purely subjective observation: my family seems to have zero preferences. My kids will watch shows on their Nintendo DS as much as their tablet as much as the Roku hooked to the TV. I think context also matters. Are we talking living room or bus, for example. Ultimately, people are after the content first and foremost.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen statistics on either fact. What I know as a person who has both tablet sizes and with many friends and colleagues with both (plus smartphones and "phablets") is they it doesn't matter. For a tv show, people will watch it on anything. The bigger screen is better, but there's a cost-benefit analysis that determines if time put into getting that larger device (or even connecting to a TV) is worth the effort over just watching it on the smaller screen.

Personally I love watching stuff on a tablet because mine has an amazing OLED display. Picture quality is way better than my tv. But there is never a case where I'd rather watch something at the end of the day on the tablet instead of the TV, where I could lounge back on the couch and relax, without having to hold a device directly. And I know that sentiment is widespread.